# background loading when android app opened from recent apps

Tags: android, android-asynctask, activity-lifecycle

I have a main activity in which there are two asynchronous calls.
This data is loaded on main screen for other two activities so that when landing activity is loaded the data should be ready for display.
Now there are cases like

- If Internet is switched off and app is clicked it comes on main screen but now there will be no data loading as there is no internet and now internet is turned on so when we click app icon it directly comes on main screen but now as main acitivity is already loaded so there will be no asynchronous calls.So data is not loaded.I have written asynchronous calls in `oncreate` method.
- when I want to exit from I give a dialog box which just displays yes or no for exiting.now what happens when I open the app sometimes the previous data is loaded and there is no asynchronous call.So on yes button I initialize response to null so as to load it again.but is this the right way.?

I am little bit confused about android activity lifecycle may be I can take help of lifecycle methods but not able find the way.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Start by reading the documentation about the Activity lifecycle @ http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: you can try doing that in `onresume()`

Comment: for the first case in which you mention AsynCall is in oncreate.. you can make a background service & start that service when u find no internet, service will check the connection in background and as soon as it gets the connection it re calls the asyn & in this way your data will be displayed on screen

Comment: I will refer documentation and try to implement thanks for suggestions.